# ¿"Autorespeto" está bien escrito?

Tags: ortografía, compuestos

Estaba buscando información sobre el "autorespeto" en Internet para mi tarea de Psicología, y mientras buscaba en Google encontré que se escribía de 3 formas:

- Auto Respeto
- Autorrespeto
- AutoRespeto

Decidí buscar en el diccionario de la RAE (DLE) pero no encontré información sobre ello.

Comment: También he visto *auto-respeto*, ejemplo: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Kangha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La ortografía sugerida por la RAE es ***autorrespeto***:

> #RAEconsultas La grafía correcta es «autorrespeto», pues el fonema /rr/ se representa siempre con el dígrafo «-rr-» cuando va entre vocales; así, «rojo», pero «infrarrojo»; «rector», pero «vicerrector», etc.
>
> - @RAEinforma, en [Twitter 14 mar. 2018](https://mobile.twitter.com/raeinforma/status/973858541747523584)